# Convert recursively and Asynchronous DocumentReference in an JS object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, google-cloud-firestore

I have this type of object:

```
{
    "www.some-domain.com": {
        "key1": ["value1"],
        "data": {
            "d1": true,
            "d2": false,
            "d3": DocumentReference {...},
            "d4": []
        },
        "key2": "value2"
    }
}
```

and I need to get, asynchronous, the data from the DocumentReference.
The problem I have is that I need to find all the DocumentReferences, convert them `.get().then((docSnap) => docSnap.data())` and put the result in the same place the DocumentReference was.

The DocumentReference can be at all levels of the object.

any idea on what is the best and fastest way to accomplish such thing?

---

the expected result of this would be something like:

`convert(data).then((convertedData) => {...})`

where the converted data would be like:

```
{
    "www.some-domain.com": {
        "key1": ["value1"],
        "data": {
            "d1": true,
            "d2": false,
            "d3": {
                "c1": "v1",
                "c2": "v2",
                "c3": {
                    "z1": "zz2"
                }

            },
            "d4": []
        },
        "key2": "value2"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be much easier if you use `async/await`s instead of regular promises.

Then you can traverse the object recursively like this:

```js
// Using lodash just for `isArray` and `isObject`. You can use vanilla js if you want
const _ = require('lodash');

const getData = async ref => (await ref.get()).data();
// Please check this function. I just mocked DocumentReference so you might need to tweak it.
const isReference = ref => ref && ref instanceof DocumentReference;

// Traverse the object stepping into nested object and arrays.
// If we find any DocumentReference then pull the data before proceeding.
const convert = async data => {
    if (_.isArray(data)) {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
            const element = data[i];

            if (isReference(element)) {
                // Replace the reference with actual data
                data[i] = await getData(data[i]);
            }

            // Note, we are passing data[i], not `element`
            // Because we want to traverse the actual data not the DocumentReference
            await convert(data[i]);
        }

        return data;
    }

    if (data && _.isObject(data)) {
        const keys = Object.keys(data);

        for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i += 1) {
            const key = keys[i];
            const value = data[key];

            if (isReference(value)) {
                data[key] = await getData(value);
            }

            // Same here. data[key], not `value`
            await convert(data[key])
        }

        return data;
    }
}

// You can use it like this
const converted = await convert(dataObject);
// Or in case you don't like async/await:
convert(dataObject).then(converted => ...);
```

Comment: Ohh man, that worked perfectly! thank you so much.
I want to note 1 thing, in the getData function it should be `(await ref.get()).data()` - data is a function.

Comment: @ElonSalfati happy I could help :) Fixed the `data()` call.