# Change vue data from promise callback

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to change my Vue data from inside a promise callback,
and for some reason, I can't see the value changes in the template,

I saw this question [how to update a vue's property in a promise call back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42590538/how-to-update-a-vues-property-in-a-promise-call-back)
and I've changed the `this` to the correct one, but still, I can't see the value changing in the template.

this is my template:

```
<template>
  {{ sites }}
</template>
```

and this is my script:

```
data: () => ({
  sites: {}
}),
methods: {
  initialize(snapshot) {
    let _this = this
    snapshot.forEach((site) => {
      convert(site.data())
        .then(converted => {
          _this.sites[site.id] = converted
        })
    })
  }
}
```

any idea why my data won't change?

Comment: what is convert there?

Comment: it's an async function that converts all firestore DocumentReference into JSON: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50597797/convert-recursively-and-asynchronous-documentreference-in-an-js-object/50600086?noredirect=1#comment88210776_50600086

Comment: Are you sure that convert isn't rejecting the promise (is `console.log(converted)` inside the `then` callback actually outputting what you expect)?

Comment: yes, it does...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's reactive issue. Please try

```
.then(converted => {
  const sites = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(_this.sites))
  sites[site.id] = converted
  _this.sites = sites
}
```

More explanation:

To update page, Vue does cheap comparison (as I understand, reference comparison). If you only update an attribute of object, they still point to same reference -> Vue will not update page. So we need to make deep copy them to make the comparison work

Comment: worked perfectly, could you explain a bit more about this subject, or refer to some documents please?

Comment: Have a look at the [Vue.js Array caveats](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats). There is also documented that you could use `Vue.$set` or `Array.prototype.splice` to detect the changes.